# What is the role of the $L_2$-norm in optimization?

Tags: optimization

I'm a little confused about the role of the $L_2$-norm in optimization. Suppose my data is $n$-dimensional data, and I have some input pairs $(x, y)$ and a function $f(x)$ which I want to learn. For my cost function, I sum up, over all training examples, the square of the difference between $y$ and $f(x)$.

I am confused about what the $L_2$-norm part of this is that people tend to talk about. Is it:

1) You are squaring the distance between each $y$ and $f(x)$ pair, therefore this summation is the $L_2$-norm of the difference over all pairs.

2) To calculate the distance between each $y$ and $f(x)$ pair, you square the difference between each element in the $n$-dimensional vector, and square root it to find the distance. This distance is the $L_2$-norm.

Which one? Thanks!

Comment: May look also at the [least square optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question well, then option 1 is the right one. By definition, the L2-norm (or $\ell^2$ norm) of a $n$-dimensional vector $\underline{x}$ is given by

$$
\|\underline{x}\|_{\ell^2} = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$

In your case, what you are minimizing is the square of the $\ell^2$ norm of $\underline{y}-\underline{f}$, where $f_i = f(x_i)$,

$$
\|\underline{y}-\underline{f}\|_{\ell^2}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - f(x_i))^2
$$

So the $\ell^2$ norm comes into play when you are measuring the *total* mismatch between data and predicted values.

Comment: Thanks. So if x and y are multi-dimensional, then $y_i - f(x_i)$ would be the Euclidean distance between the two vectors? Isn't this also the L2-norm?

Comment: If at every point $f(x_i)$ and $y$ are multi-dimensional, then you can replace $(y_i-f(x_i))^2$ with $\|\underline{y}_i - \underline{f}(x_i)\|^2$.

Comment: L2 is not robust.  It is optimal for Gaussian noise, but if you have outliers, the least squares will tend to be dominated by these outliers.  It is possible to adapt nonlinear conjugate gradient to get both fast and robust optimization.  Of course, you can also use direct methods such as simplex.

Comment: That's a whole different topic. He was just asking what the definition of L2 norm was.